# Probability Question for Intro Stats Course

Tags: probability

I'm new to probability and I'm struggling to figure how to approach this question.

Airport A handles 40% of all airline traffic, and airports B and C handle 40% and 20% respectively. The detection rate for weapons at the three airports are 0.9, 0.5 and 0.4 respectively. If a passenger is found to be carrying a weapon what is the probability that he is using airport A?

Sorry if it's very simple.

Comment: Do you mean that 90% of passengers at airport A are detected with a weapon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that 90% of passengers at airport A are detected with a weapon, one way to solve this is to just compute out the all the percentages of 6 types of passengers 3 airports by whether or not they got detected.

Sometimes when starting out with statistics, instead of thinking about percentages, it's easier to imagine 100 actual passengers. These 100 passengers breakdown as in the image below.

[image]

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{Airport}& \text{A}& \text{B}& \text{C}& \text{Total} \\ \hline
\text{Passengers} & 40& 40& 20& 100  \\ \hline
\text{Detected} & 36& 20& 8& 64  \\ \hline
\text{Not Detected} & 4 & 20 & 12 & 36   \\ \hline
\text{Probability Detected was from this Airport} & \frac{36}{64}=\frac{9}{16} & \frac{20}{64}=\frac{5}{16} & \frac{8}{64}=\frac{1}{8} & -  \\ \hline
\text{% Chance Detected was from this Airport} & 56.25\% & 31.25\% & 12.5\% & -  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

So I believe your answer would be $56.25\%$ if i understood your question.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate how clear your answer is and I love the visual aids!

Answer (score 0):

Often problems like these are confusing because the assumptions are unclear.  For example, are we to assume that the bad guys' choices are uneffected by  these numbers?  Personally, I'd go for airport $C$ as my chances are best there.

But, let's say the bad guy doesn't know the detection probabilities and that bad guys follow the standard population distribution for airport selection.

Then, your assumptions mean:  if we start with a generic bad guy, he has a $.4\times .9=.36$ chance of being caught at $A$, a $.4\times .5=.2$ chance of being caught at $B$, and a $.2\times .4=.08$ chance of being caught at $C$.

To get a feeling for this, say we start with $100$ independent bad guys.  then we expect that $36$ of them will get caught at $A$, $20$ will get caught at $B$, and $8$ will be caught at $C$ (and $100-36-20-8=36$ will successfully get their weapon on board).

it follows that the probability that an arrest occurs at $A$ (given that it occurs at all) is $\frac {36}{64}=\boxed {\frac {9}{16}}$.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped a lot but it wasn't clear why it was that the final ratio was out of 64 where as the other answer was a bit more clear on this.